# PHP: Best way to convert a datetime to just time string?

Tags: php, datetime, time

I have a datetime that I pulled from the database that looks like this: `2000-01-01 08:00:00`

Now I need to convert it so all I have left is: `08:00:00`

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: The simplest way would be to do a `TIME(column)` when pulling it from the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I should have thought of this earlier...easiest way would be to use the MySQL `TIME()` function to only select the time in the first place.

Answer (score 4):

```
substr('2000-01-01 08:00:00', 11);
```

Comment: +1: If the result is always in DATETIME format, this is the safest way. Real date parsing always carries the risk of timestamp funkiness interfering (that is usally desired, but not here)

Answer (score 4):

You could use

```
substr($timestamp, -8);
```

Comment: I was typing my answer at the same time as you, had I saw yours, I would have not submitted :-p..But yes, either works just fine.

Answer (score 1):

you can also use the php strtotime function to turn it into a datetime object, then use the format method on it to get a pretty representation however you want. That way you can put in am/pm, do 24 hour or 12 hour, do whatever you want with the date, etc.

```
$date = strtotime('2000-01-01 08:00:00');
echo $date->format('H:i:s');
```

Comment: This is the actual answer.  the accepted answer is what the asker ended up doing, but isnt the answer to the question that was asked.

Comment: This answer appears to be untested hogwash which will only confuse and mislead researchers.  `strtotime()` DOES NOT produce a datetime object!  https://3v4l.org/aY33q The responsible thing to do would be to pull this post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use date and enter the needed time format after parsing timestamp to str

```
date('h:i a', strtotime('2000-01-01 08:00:00'))
```