# Convert output to a readable time

Tags: php, api

Well, I am working with twitch's API currently and I want to `echo` the time that the current stream started at. Currently the following is output: `2015-04-11T07:45:20Z seconds` so I am wondering how I would convert this into a readable time. i.e. `07:45:20`.

Comment: Is `seconds` actually part of that value?

Comment: @JohnConde It is part of the output from the API if thats what you mean.

Comment: [Get time from a date/time string](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6955838), [PHP: Best way to convert a datetime to just time string?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4349033)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) allows you to read in non-standard date input and turn it into a `DateTime` object that you can then use to format your output however you like:

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z *', '2015-04-11T07:45:20Z seconds');
echo $date->format('H:i:s');  // 07:45:20
```

[<kbd>Demo</kbd>](https://eval.in/312025)